# `lmodern` package reduces the size of automatically sized delimiters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, lmodern

Including `lmodern` package reduces the size of `\left` and `\right` delimiters.  For example, try this with and without `lmodern`:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}  % <<<

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Is this a feature or a bug?
What it the "correct" behaviour?
If this is a bug, is there a fix?

Note that Latin Modern used in XeLaTeX does not reduce the size of delimiters, but using `lmodern` package with XeLaTeX also reduces the size of delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One fraction is sufficient to show the problem.

Load the `fixcmex` package and consult its documentation to see where the problem lies.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lmodern}  % <<<
\usepackage{fixcmex}


\begin{document}

\[  
\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sum
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here's the output without `fixcmex`; as you see, not only the parentheses are wrong, also the summation sign is smaller.

[image]