# Tilde sign in URL is appearing in superscipt position

Tags: biblatex, fonts, urls, superscripts, tilde

The Tilde (~) sign in the URL appears in the superscript position. How can I change it so that it gets the same position (near the normal line) as in the text here?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@online{pope2021,
  title = {Lectures on Geometry and Group Theory},
  author = {Pope, C.},
  date = {2021},
  url = {https://people.tamu.edu/~c-pope/geom-group.pdf},
  urldate = {2024-03-03},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{Testing URL in bibliography}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1]
\url{https://people.tamu.edu/~c-pope/geom-group.pdf} \cite{pope2021}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `utf8` has been the default input encoding for all TeX engines for the last half dozen years or so. Unless your TeX distribution is prehistorically ancient, you needn't run `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: You can change the font URLs are displayed in to one which contains a tilde more to your liking.

Comment: @Mico I wasn't aware of this `utf8` thing. I kept using both `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} ` from some other templates. Also, maybe I checked this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44701/114006) as well. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: @raf You still want `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I'd assume that's never going to be default. At least, there are excellent reasons it shouldn't be.

Comment: @cfr I like to know more about it.

Comment: @raf About what? Why you probably want to keep it or why it shouldn't be default? Or something else?

Comment: @cfr you mean I should keep `fontenc` here, but it shouldn't be used by default, right? Why shouldn't it be? Can I safely omit both of them if not asked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152292/discussion-between-cfr-and-raf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using pdfLaTeX to compile your document and wish to keep using the default font family (which is called "Computer Roman"), one simple fix would consist of not loading the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`. However, depending on your document setup, this may cause new, and possibly nastier, problems. A much better choice would be to keep running `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and to start loading the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package with the option `lowtilde`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[lowtilde]{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{https://people.tamu.edu/~c-pope/geom-group.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that option (a) is likely to lead to problems with other characters. I suspect a lot of users get those basic preamble lines from templates/editors etc. without knowing what they are for.

Comment: @cfr - I did write that the second option was much better; however, that may still have been too subtle. Let me come up with a more forceful recommendation. :-)

Comment: (+1) for `xurl` which I'd never heard of. Or never registered in my brain, anyway. Think I'm going to be adding it to my standard configurations ....

Comment: Thank you. In my main document, I loaded `xurl` after `hyperref` and `biblatex`. In that order, putting the option `lowtilde` didn't change anything. Seems like I need to load `xurl` first. Is there any automated way to keep my preamble (packages+setup) in a proper order?

Comment: @raf - I believe what matters here is loading `xurl` before `biblatex`. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any automated way of successfully sequencing the instructions contained in the preamble.

Comment: @Mico I just tested loading these 3 packages in the order `hyperref`,  `xurl`, `biblatex`.  Only putting `xurl` gives me the desired output. Is it recommended to keep the order `xurl`, `biblatex`, `hyperref`?

Comment: @raf - I'm afraid I'm not much of an expert on which package loading sequence is best. That said, with few exceptions it's usually best to load `hyperref` *last*. (One of the exceptions is the `cleveref` package, which definitely should be loaded after `hyperref`.) Regarding the other two packages, I think you've established that `xurl` should be loaded before `biblatex`.

Comment: @Mico, I get your point. Thank you,

Comment: Another package in my preamble is `bookmark` and it also requires to be loaded after `hyperref`. I came to know here's a dedicated discussion on the ordering conflicts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/114006

Comment: @raf - There's a reason why I wrote "One of the exceptions".  :-) As you've (re)discovered, `bookmarks` is another exception to the rule...

Answer (score 4):

If you use Latin Modern rather than Computer Modern, you will get the low tilde by default and can keep the `T1` encoding. I would use `cfr-lm` for Latin Modern, but `lmodern` is sufficient in this case. Latin Modern is based on Computer Modern but was developed later with a wider range of languages in mind.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}% I would use cfr-lm
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@online{pope2021,
  title = {Lectures on Geometry and Group Theory},
  author = {Pope, C.},
  date = {2021},
  url = {https://people.tamu.edu/~c-pope/geom-group.pdf},
  urldate = {2024-03-03},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{Testing URL in bibliography}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1]
\url{https://people.tamu.edu/~c-pope/geom-group.pdf} \cite{pope2021}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]

\end{document}
```

I'm not going to post an image because my images suck right now due to an Okular/KDE bug.

[But you should do what [Mico said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714193/) and load `xurl`, whether you stick to Computer Modern or decide to switch to Latin Modern.]

Comment: +1 for "I would use cfr-lm". :-)

Comment: Thank you. I preferred not to load `lmodern` for this issue:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512659/114

Comment: @raf Thanks for drawing my attention to `fixcmex` and the issue it addresses. As that answer points out, Latin Modern is, in many respects, superior to Computer Modern. And as shown there, loading `fixcmex` fixes the issue and does so in the same way you're fixing it for Computer Modern when loading `amsmath`. So that's a slightly strange reason not to use LM, if you don't mind my saying so.

Comment: @cfr I get it your point. Thank you.